# Dynamically adjusting a sort network size, an easy way to increase by one

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sorting-network

Insetion sort, rewritten as a sort network produces something like this:

[image]

It sorts six items, for example using the following comparisons:

```
[0,1]
[1,2][0,1]
[2,3][1,2][0,1]
[3,4][2,3][1,2][0,1]
[4,5][3,4][2,3][1,2][0,1]
```

Now lets say I have a seventh value I want sorted. The modification is trivial, adding another set/line of comparisons...

```
[5,6][4,5][3,4][2,3][1,2][0,1]
```

Other sorts such as bitonic require more complex modifications, particularly in that additions need to be made all over the place to previous lines.

**My question is this:** *Are there any other sorts, like insertion, that allow easy one-line additions to support extra items in the search?* I'm particularly interested in the lower computational complexity sorts like bitonic.

Comment: Easy for a human or easy for a computer program?

Comment: @Shahbaz both - I'm after speed. The adjustment for insertion could be surrounded by a single conditional - nice and fast.